# Expect element to not exist timeout when the element doesn't exist

Tags: react-native, detox

I'm trying to verify that an element doesn't exist. But when I do:

```
await waitFor(element(by.label('Erro'))).toNotExist().withTimeout(800);
await expect(element(by.label('Erro'))).toNotExist();
```

I'm getting " Error: Timeout of 240000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves."

> Detox: 5.10.0
>   Node: 5.6.0
>   Device: IPhone 6s plus (emulator)
>   Xcode: 9.2
>   macOS: Sierra 10.12.6

Device and verbose Detox logs

> detox verb ws send: {"type":"invoke","params":{"target":{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"EarlGrey","value":"instance"},"method":"detox_selectElementWithMatcher:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"detox_matcherForAccessibilityLabel:","args":[{"type":"NSString","value":"Saldo de conta-corrente"}]}}]}},"method":"atIndex:","args":[{"type":"NSInteger","value":0}]}},"method":"performAction:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYActions"},"method":"actionForTap","args":[]}}]},"messageId":10}
>   detox verb ws onMessage: {"type":"invokeResult","messageId":10,"params":{"result":"(GREYElementInteraction)"}}
>   detox verb ws
>   detox verb ws send: {"type":"invoke","params":{"target":{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYCondition"},"method":"detoxConditionForNotElementMatched:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"EarlGrey","value":"instance"},"method":"detox_selectElementWithMatcher:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"detoxMatcherForBoth:and:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"detox_matcherForAccessibilityLabel:","args":[{"type":"NSString","value":"Erro"}]}},{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"matcherForNotNil","args":[]}}]}}]}}]}},"method":"waitWithTimeout:","args":[{"type":"CGFloat","value":0.8}]},"messageId":11}
>   1) Saldo conta corrente
>
> detox verb ws send: {"type":"cleanup","params":{"stopRunner":false},"messageId":12}
>   detox verb ws onMessage: {"type":"cleanupDone","messageId":12,"params":{}}
>   detox verb ws
>
> 0 passing (4m)
>   1 failing
>
> Consultas Saldo conta corrente:
>   Error: Timeout of 240000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

Comment: what happens if you wrap that code with "await device.disableSynchronization();" and then "await device.enableSynchronization();"?

Comment: @Antoni4, wraped the code as you said, keep getting the timeout.